# Hibernate Lazyloading not working on @Transactional method

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am facing the so much discussed ""

I'm working on a spring boot application using hibernate.

As far I know, if an attribute of an Entity is marked as FetchType.LAZY, with need to have a Hibernate session to be able to trigger the respective query to bring the related entity.

Following is a method that retrieves a List of entities from a parent entity:

```
@Transactional
public List<Portfolio> getSharedPortfolios(String userName){
    User user = userService.getUserActive(userName);
    List<Portfolio> sharedPortfolios = user.getSharedPortfolios();
    //logger.debug("Number of Shared Portfolios: " + sharedPortfolios.size());  <======
    return sharedPortfolios;
}
```

The **getSharedPortfolios** method is being called from a controller and getting the "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException" then try to access this List (PersistentBag)

Being **getSharedPortfolios** method annotated with the @Transactional annotation, i was expecting that when user.getSharedPortfolios() (sharedPortfolios is a Lazy Fetch List) is executed, the respective list is initialized. But is not happening that.

Can someone explain to me why? And Why if i uncomment the log line that prints the size of that PersistentBag, the exception is not thrown?

Do I need in this case explicitly initialise it using EntityManager?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `List<Portfolio> sharedPortfolios = user.getSharedPortfolios();` the value assigned to `sharedPortfolios` is a lazy proxy.

If you simply return `sharedPortfolios` and access it outside your `@Transactional` method, you get `LazyInitializationException`

On the other hand, if you access `sharedPortfolios` within your `@Transactional` method, the initialization occurs, and you return already initialized data.

IMHO what you describe is expected behaviour.

There are multiple ways to force the fetch:

- entity graph
- jpql (fetch)
- criteria query (fetch)
- manually accessing the variable (as shown in your example)

Alternatively, check the setting
`spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this means

> "The getSharedPortfolios method is being called from a controller"

so this might not be your case but the `@Transactional` annotation will not work if you are calling the `getSharedPortfolios` method from another method within the same class.